# Conditionally enabling systemd files through Debian packaging

Tags: systemd, dpkg

I've created a [deb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_(file_format)) package which installs a service.

On our embedded devices, I want this package to automatically enable the service.  On our developer workstations, I want the developers to `systemctl start foo` manually (it's a heavy service, and so it just consumes resources if run all of the time on a desktop environment).

How can I go about prompting the user for their decision during the `apt-get` step? Is that the best solution?

Note, I've created the package using `dh_make` and `debhelper` and enabled it with:

```
%:
    dh $@ --with=systemd

override_dh_systemd_enable:
    dh_systemd_enable --name=foo foo.service
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [systemd presets](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.preset.html) to affect whether a systemd service will default to being enabled or disabled at installation time.

The Debian presets default to enabling all services as they're installed, so you only need to ship a preset to the development workstations (the default behavior matches what you want to happen in production), by shipping a file such as `/etc/systemd/system-preset/80-foo.preset` containing a line that says

```
disable foo.service
```

If you manage your developer workstations using a system such as Puppet, Chef, Ansible, etc., you can use them to ship such a systemd preset configuration, that should make it easy for you to apply the policy to developer workstations only and not production machines.

Your .deb package should use the `systemctl preset` command to enable the service, since that command will respect the preset configuration.

As [@JdeBP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/5132/jdebp) and [@sourcejedi](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/29483/sourcejedi) point out, the Debian macros in deb-helpers (such as `dh_systemd_enable`) do that already, they invoke `deb-systemd-helper` which will use `systemctl preset` by default (with a small caveat that if you remove (but do not purge) the package, and later re-install it, it will then not enable the service, even if you remove the preset file.) See [this comment in `deb-systemd-helper`'s `enable` operation](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/init-system-helpers/blob/debian/1.56/script/deb-systemd-helper#L261):

> ```
>     # We use 'systemctl preset' on the initial installation only.
>     # On upgrade, we manually add the missing symlinks only if the
>     # service already has some links installed. Using 'systemctl
>     # preset' allows administrators and downstreams to alter the
>     # enable policy using systemd-native tools.
> ```

For more information on the systemd feature of presets, see the man page of [systemd presets](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.preset.html) and of the command [`systemctl preset`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#preset%20UNIT%E2%80%A6) which implements it.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  I deploy the dev environment through a meta-package and so I can install these `*.preset` files as part of that package.

Comment: An important quirk to know is that presets are only consulted by `deb-systemd-helper` the first time that a package is installed.  After that, the parallel database maintained by the Debian tools is consulted instead, until the package is purged.  https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=18320131

Comment: So `deb-systemd-helper` appears to use presets. And this should work without needing a manual systemctl preset command inside the .deb package. The Debian-specific quirk is what happens if you remove (but do not purge) the package. If you later re-install the package, it will then not enable the service, even if you remove the preset file. https://salsa.debian.org/debian/init-system-helpers/blob/debian/1.56/script/deb-systemd-helper

Comment: @sourcejedi Incorporated your comments and link to deb-systemd-helper comment into the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to prompt the user during installation, [you should use `debconf`](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-binary.html#prompting-in-maintainer-scripts). This has a number of advantages, even if you’re not in a context where Debian Policy is relevant: it provides a consistent end-user experience, with support for a variety of frontends; it supports different “levels”; it supports pre-seeding. Pre-seeding means that the package can be pre-configured, in which case it won’t prompt at all. The different levels mean that a prompt can be set up to only show in certain circumstances; you could then have the package install without prompting by default (for your embedded targets), and instruct your developers to set up their frontend appropriately when installing the package so that they see the prompt.

However, I think it’s better to avoid prompting altogether when possible. This is especially true for services which have other ways of dealing with end-user preferences, and where dealing with user preferences complicates the maintainer scripts (see the generated scripts in your package, they already deal with a number of subtle issues, using `deb-systemd-helper` — you’d have to replicate all that, with your preference handling on top).

If your developers never need to run the service, they can mask it before installing the package, and the service will never be enabled:

```
sudo systemctl mask foo
```

If your developers sometimes need to run the service, using the systemd unit, they can disable it after installing the package for the first time, and subsequent installs will remember this:

```
sudo apt install foo
sudo systemctl disable --now foo
```

The default would then be to enable the service.

Comment: Good answer.  `debconf` looks like what I had in mind, but I agree that it's best to avoid prompting when possible.  I knew about the `systemctl disable`, but I was trying to help the user to avoid "skipping a step" during installation.  The `*.presets` solution suggested by Filippe solves this.

Comment: Indeed, presets fit the bill perfectly!